# When the SVM will be a better option to using than CNN

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, svm

I want to use a dataset with five features related to three classes ( normal, UDP, and SYN) to detect the DDoS attack, In this idea, which algorithm should be used ( ML with SVM or DL with CNN) and when will SVM be a better option to use than CNN? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, CNNs work well when the data has some spatial relationship. For the context you provided it doesn't seem to be the case. Considering this, if you had to make a strict choice in between the two the SVM makes more sense. Although, I'd suggest you to research and try other methods. For example, if you are interested in using a neural network for your classification problem [This article](https://towardsdatascience.com/the-complete-guide-to-neural-networks-multinomial-classification-4fe88bde7839) could be useful.